# How to search for a file or directory in Linux Ubuntu machine

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 64 bit) and attached a volume from a publicly available snapshot to the instance. I successfully mounted the volume. I am supposed to be able to run a script from this attached volume using the following steps as explained in the tutorial:

```
Log in to your virtual machine. 
mkdir /space 
mount /dev/sdf1 /space 
cd /space 
./setup-script
```

The problem is that, when I try: ./setup-script I got the following message: 
-bash: ./setup-script: No such file or directory

What is the problem ? How can I search for the ./setup-script in the whole machine ? I'm not very familiar with linux system. Please, help.

For more details about the issue: Look at my previous post: 
[Error when mounting drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544502/error-when-mounting-drive)

Comment: mkdir /space; mount /dev/sdf1 /space; cd /space; ./setup-script

Comment: This is what i did exactly. I will edit the port. It was a typing mistake.

Comment: ls -la /space   what does this say

Comment: @marabutt: I get the following list: . ;  .. ; bin ; boot ; dev ; etc ; home ; initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-virtual ; lib ; lib64 ; lost+found ; media ; mnt ; opt ; proc ; root ; run ; sbin ; selinux ; space ; srv ; sys ; tmp ; usr ; var ; vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-virtual. NOTE: the directory space seems like a loop, whenever I type: cd space, I then type: ls , I find the directory again and again.

Comment: I don't find any directory named setup-script. But this is what is written in the tutorial, see step 5 in: https://www.eff.org/pages/howto-using-ssl-observatory-cloud. How can I search about this setup-script everywhere in the machine ??

Answer (score 0):

```
# Is it a script or an executable ?
file /space/setup-script
# Show us it is readable and marked executable
ls -l /space/setup-script
# Mark it executable
chmod a+x /space/setup-script
# Then try running it again?  If you know it is shell script you can:
bash /space/setup-script
```

If still not working, then we get into why it wont execute.

```
grep space /proc/mounts
```

Does the options it have `noexec` ?

Try `mount -o remount,exec /space` now try your instructions again.

NOTE: All commands presume you are 'root' user or you can 'sudo' each command.

Comment: The problem is that I get: ls: cannot access /space/setup-script: No such file or directory. I have attached a volume from a public snapshot and the tutorial says that I am supposed to find setup-script and be able to run the script. See step 5 at: https://www.eff.org/pages/howto-using-ssl-observatory-cloud . I have made mount but using the following command instead of what they wrote:  sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /space. Then, I am not able to find continue step 5 due to the fact that I can't find such file or directory (setup-script). How can I search for it ?

Comment: but you are able to `cd /space` and then `ls -l` and you can see the files you expect, including `setup-script` ?  The command `df` shows the volumes mounted, your /space should be listed there (if it is mounted).

Comment: No. I can't see the `setup-script` when I `ls -l`.

Comment: But a volume is mounted in /space ?  Then you mounted the wrong volume, or the data you expected has been deleted from it.

Comment: It is v. low probability that the data has been moved. But, my question is: the tutorial is saying that: mount /dev/sdf1 /space but I performed: sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /space. Could this be a reason or there is nothing wrong with this?

Comment: it sounds like you're not mounting the proper device. If you assigned your EBS to sdf than you need to do "mount /dev/xvdf1 /space" or add that to your fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have mounted the wrong device. I've just recalled a trick you can use to find the device name of an EBS volume in Linux, since it is often different from the device name reported in the AWS console. First unmount the device in Linux, then detach it from the instance using the AWS console, so we go back to the original state. Now run this command in Linux:

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

The command will show the volumes currently attached. The next step is to attach the volume to the instance using the AWS console, and then to run that same command again in Linux. You should see an additional line appear. This line will tell you the name of the device to mount. For example, I get this output in my Ubuntu instance:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        1    8388608 xvda1
 202       80    8388608 xvdf
```

The first line was already there before I attached the volume, so I know this is my root volume. The second line is the one that appeared, so in this case, the device to mount would be `/dev/xvdf`.

Comment: For the unmount, I'm facing a problem. I mounted using the following command: `sudo mount /dev/xvda1 /space` , I unmount using the following:  `sudo umount /dev/xvda1` and I get: `umount: /: device is busy.(In some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))`. I also tried:  `sudo umount /space` and `got: umount: /space: not mounted`. What should I do to unmount it?

Comment: I could unmount by using `sudo umount -l /dev/xvda1`. But, when trying to `cat /proc/partitions`, I get: `cat: proc/partitions: No such file or directory`. I am in the root, I could list and found a directory names proc but it does not contain anything. I tried to list proc but it shows total 0. please, advise.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why you don't have /proc/partitions. It is usually standard in Ubuntu. I'm puzzled.

Comment: It worked now. Before attach, I got:   `202        1    8388608 xvda1
 202       16  880737792 xvdb`. After attach, I got: 
 `202        1    8388608 xvda1
 202       16  880737792 xvdb
 202       80   94371840 xvdf
 202       81   85979848 xvdf1`. To which one should I mount? there are two volumes added ?

Comment: I got: mount: unknown filesystem type 'jfs'. Do you think I should change the instance type from Ubuntu to something else?

Comment: Try installing the jfsutils package: `sudo apt-get install jfsutils`. If it still doesn't work, try running `sudo depmod -a` before mounting.