# The attached volume does not appear

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an instance that I need to attach and mount a volume to it. I have some unsuccessful attempts, then finally, I unmounted the volume.

Then I performed the following command `sudo df -h` to know the volumes before I attach the volume from a public snapshot. I got:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  989M  6.7G  13% /
udev             17G  8.0K   17G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.7G  164K  6.7G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             17G     0   17G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       827G  201M  785G   1% /mnt
```

Then, I attached a volume (that I created from a publicly available snapshot) to my instance. See:
[image]

Then, I made sure that the status for the volume is attached to my instance. I performed the command again. I got the same previous output before I attach the volume.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  989M  6.7G  13% /
udev             17G  8.0K   17G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.7G  172K  6.7G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             17G     0   17G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       827G  201M  785G   1% /mnt
```

The reason that I am doing this is that I need to mount the newly attached volume. There were several unsuccessful attempts in this post if you need more information about my problem: [How to search for a file or directory in Linux Ubuntu machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547409/how-to-search-for-a-file-or-directory-in-linux-ubuntu-machine)

Please, help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After attaching the volume, you still have to mount it:

```
mount -t <fs_type> /dev/xvdf /path/to/your/directory
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know to which device I mount. In your command, how did you know that I have to mount to /dev/xvdf ??

Comment: In the "Attach Volume" dialogue from the Amazon Console, you can specify which device your volume should be - in your case /dev/sdf (which gets translated to /dev/xvdf).

Comment: How can I find the approperiate <fs_type> ?

Comment: You said you were using a public snapshot. According to the [Amazon Public Dataset docs](http://aws.amazon.com/en/publicdatasets/), these should be in ISO9660 or EXT3 filesystem types. So your fs_type for the mount command should be `iso9660` or `ext3`.

Comment: Still not able to.. `$ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/xvdf /space` , I get: `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail  or so.

Comment: Then I tried: 
`$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/xvdf /space`, and I got: 
`mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so. I am following a tutorial, specifically, stuck in step 5, this might help: https://www.eff.org/pages/howto-using-ssl-observatory-cloud

Comment: Well this is a custom dataset - but the filesystem type is given in the link: `provided it can mount JFS filesystems.` Therefore try `mount -t jfs`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still fairly inexperienced at Unix sysadmin (enough to be dangerous?), but I had exactly this problem - according to the AWS console, the volume should be attached at /dev/sdj, but it wasn't.

Then I noticed that my previous volume (listed as /dev/sda1), wasn't there either, but instead was called /dev/xvda1.  Tiny bit of pattern recognition later and I realised that my volume was listed under xvdj

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdj /path/to/your/directory
```

... and the mounted volume was the one I was looking for.

Maybe someone can fill me in on why, in the comments?

Comment: Just noticed a helpful explanation on the AWS dialog box, duh... Note: Newer linux kernels may rename your devices to /dev/xvdf through /dev/xvdp internally, even when the device name entered here (and shown in the details) is /dev/sdf through /dev/sdp.