# Adding recovered volume to an AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

So, the story is a bit long... but in a nutshell: I had a ec2 microinstance and I lost the connection with it by doing, installing and running whereami (silly me). Then I took a snapshot of the instance and created a volume from it. Then I created a new micro instance and added that volume I got from the one I broke, so now this new instance has two drives sda1 (by default) and sdf (which is the one I added), I atached it from the AWS panel and now I'd like to mount it on my new instance, but I cannot get it.
I installed the AWS complement for it `sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools ec2-ami-tools` but even know it fails. I tried `ec2-attach-volume volume_id -i instance_id -d device` like this:

```
ec2-attach-volume vol-4d826724 -i i-6058a509 -d /dev/sdf
```

But now it asks me for a key: `Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)`

And I am quite stuck on this...
Of course I do not want to format the drive I'm adding because I want to recover the information it has.

Comment: Use the `mount` commands. Once its attached to the instance, the ec2 tools wont help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already attached the volume from the AWS Management Console, you don't need to run `ec2-attach-volume`. You just need to mount it. You can find instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html).

If you get a message saying that the device does not exist, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544502/error-when-mounting-drive/12546040#12546040).

Comment: OK, I think I got it... I was beating around the bushes far too much.

So I just created a folder and mounted there my volume, without formatting it.

In detail, I saw with `df -h` that my main volume was /dev/xvda1 even-though in the panel of AWS was called /dev/sda1

So I did:

    `sudo mkdir /mnt/disk2`
    `sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/disk2`

And was solved. 

I found inspiration here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00rq00000054000000

But remember not to format the volume with `mkfs` if you do not want to lose all the data.